# Scrolling UITableView methods

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I need to get event then UITableView scrolling up and down. How can I do it?

this not working

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Comment: FYI, `scrollViewDidScrollToTop:` is only fired when user tap status bar to go to top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;

    if (offset.y > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"scorlling up");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"scorlling down");
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, it fires but I can not detect did I scroll to top or to bottom

Comment: @user3527777 Check the offset to detect the scroll position

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott, and I need compare it with previous offset?

Comment: @user3527777 you can save the previous offset value in class level variable or in userdefaults